# Data binding sometimes works for a FlowDocument sometimes doesn't

Tags: wpf, data-binding, flowdocument

I've slightly modified the example from:

http://www.bradcurtis.com/2010/02/06/document-and-report-generation-using-xaml-wpf-databinding-and-xps/

and used FlowDocument instead of FixedDocument.
 
I have one or two BlockUIContainer tags, one with a listbox the other one with a textbox,
binding to an XmlDataProvider in the code.
However, sometimes the binding work, sometimes it doesn't, seems to be completely random.
I've tried putting the line:

```
dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate { return null; }), null);
```

into some kind of loop, but it doesn't help. Any idea why binding does not work and what can be done to make it work consistently?
Thank you!

Update:
it started to work consistently when I put the whole contents of "InjectData" into
a loop with 10 iterations, but I am wondering if there's maybe a less lame method...

Comment: adding the loop helped on one computer only, though:(

Comment: I implemented the sample from your link.  I cannot reproduce the error you are seeing.  It works consistently for me.  In which ways did you modify the example?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but no number of iterations I can come up with solves it. I have an suspicion something about the scheduling of the binding causes it to be hardware dependent. Maybe my 8 core machine never gets to it.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but in my case the problem is linked to data templates. As soon as I have a `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type SomeType}">...</DataTemplate>` and try to render it using a `ContentControl` the binding does not work. @Greg, did you find a reliable solution to your problem?